# How to delete all rows of a multiple entry even if just one row meets defined criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the current (incomplete) code I'm using which works fine to delete any one given row, but what I really need to do is identify rows which meet certain criteria:
*Cell Value in Column L > 90%*
OR
*Cell Value in Column M > 90%*

Then if either of those is true I need to find the Cell Value in same row Column G and delete all rows which contain that same Value in Column G.

```
   Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Multiple_Criteria()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    For iCntr = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, "L") > 0.90 OR Cells(iCntr, "M") > 0.90 Then
            Cells(iCntr, "G").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next iCntr
  End Sub
```

--

[image]

What I hope to accomplish in my example would result in the only Serial # which is NOT deleted would be 1910910

thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You could add a helper column which returns the col G value if your conditions are met (blank otherwise) and then filter on that column and delete anything with a value in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ToDelete()

    Dim last_row&

    '// NOTE! The code assumes that range:
    '// 1) starts in column A
    '// 2) ends in column O
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    '// Helper column 1
    With Range("P2:P" & last_row)
        .Formula = "=IF(OR(M2>0.9,L2>0.9),1,0)"
        .Value = .Value 'Overwrite formula
    End With
    '// Helper column 2
    With Range("Q2:Q" & last_row)
        .Formula = "=IF(SUMIF(G:G,G2,P:P)>0,1,0)"
        .Value = .Value 'Overwrite formula
    End With

    Rows(1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:=1
    Rows("2:" & last_row).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False 'Remove filter
    Columns("P:Q").Delete 'Remove helper columns

End Sub
```